# Error message when trying to run fortran code in Atom or Sublime text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, atom-editor, gfortran

When I try to compile and run a fortran code in Atom or Sublime text I get the same error message. It says: "I don't understand 'm' flag!". I haven't set any flags so I don't understand this message. I use a fortran IDE and it works fine. All 3 use gfortran. Why do I get this message and is there a way to fix this.

Comment: What package are you using to provide your Fortran support to Sublime? Or do you have a custom build system?

Comment: No, Sublime has installed an option to run fortran using gfortran. I just use the build package installed in Sublime.  It tries to build my code but gives that message.

Comment: In Atom I run code like its a script using a run script package I use for python. With the f90 extension on my filename, it tried to compile and run it.  Or so I think.  As I said, my fortran IDE has no issues.

Comment: Do you get syntax highlighting?  My stock version of Sublime doesn't seem to have fortran support.

Comment: Yes sorry. I have the syntax highlighting for both.

Comment: It looks like I have 2 syntax highlighters. Don't know why. I probably just loaded anything that said fortran using the command palette. lol...

Comment: Under the tools menu is an option to set language for build system. I of course chose gfortran.

Comment: I installed the obvious Fortran packages in PackgeControl and verified that none of the build systems there use any `-m` flag, as you've noticed. However, I did come across the following github conversation talking about someone having the same error in some context, which seems to indicate that you maybe have to use a different fortran compiler. Possibly you have more than one version installed and the IDE is using the correct one while Sublime/Atom are using the wrong one: https://github.com/jbwhit/til/issues/3

Comment: thank you. It sounds like using g77 instead of gfortran may work. but i don't know how to change that.  Seems to be defined by the app itself.